# How do I set up a More Link in a View's Pager?

Tags: 7, views

I have a View and am using the Pager to display a specific number of items, limited to 4. I want to create a "More" link to link to the rest of the items.

I've set my view up as such:

[image]

But no More link is appearing, even though I have more than 4 items and even though the helper information says:

> This will add a more link to the bottom of this view, which will link to the page view. If you have more than one page view, the link will point to the display specified in 'Link display' section under advanced. You can override the url at the link display setting.

I've looked through the HTML to ensure the link is not hidden by anything else. It's simply not present.

Would anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: Have you set the link in the advanced settings? Is your View of the type Page?

Comment: @Jeroen is right. The 'more link' links to another page where one can find more content. This should however be a page display within the same view. So you can create a block display in views where you enable the more link, but within the same view you should have one or more page displays for the 'more link' to link to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make display as page then only more will work. For more details https://www.drupal.org/node/450736.

You can also create block and activate ajax for better functionality. Show more/load more modules implements this sort of functionality. You can follow that.